# How do I pass a variable to a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

From main activity I call a broadcast receiver with alarm manager for start repeat function. I create also share preference for period time. How do I pass period time integer to another class broadcast receiver?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataiowebusb" ,  VATE);


      String strUpdatetime = preferences.getString("Period","3");

      text5.setText(strUpdatetime);

      Tperiod =Integer.parseInt(strUpdatetime);

        if(Tperiod>1200){
            Tperiod=1200;//20min
        }

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(this,MyScheduleReceiver.class));//Call ala   

}

    public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static int period=20;

private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * period;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
```

If I use shared preferences inside the broadcast receiver class I have errors MODE_PRIVATE..

Comment: `How i pass integer to another class broadcast receiver?` which integer ?

Comment: Tperiod...integer from activity

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data on the `Intent` object using the `extras` attribute and its accesor method [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and retrieve data with [getIntExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

So, your calling code should look like:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyScheduleReceiver.class)
intent.putExtra("PERIOD", Tperiod);
sendBroadcast(intent);//Call ala
```

To retireve it, at your receiver `onReceive` method:

```
int tPeriod= intent.getIntExtra("PERIOD", 1200); //taking 1200 as a default value, used if no "PERIOD" Bondle is found at the Intent extras.
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating Intent put some data into bundle (Extras)

```
new Intent(this, SomeClass.class).putExtra("someKey", someValue);
```

When on broadcastReceiver, read data from intent onReceive method

```
intent.getExtras().getInt("someKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in intent extras.

**Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
i.putextra("key",value);**